# Samsung Bootloop no recovery A10

Tags: boot-loop

So i was in the middle of installing twrp custom recovery on a Samsung A10 (SM-A105FN) but something went wrong. I dont know what or how it failed i just know that it did, and that custom recovery is blocking my normal/default recovery. Which brings me to the point where if i press the volume down button and power button it does turn with the error message that the phone is not running offical samsung software on but no recovery screen no nothing. Its in a bootloop with no recovery mode basically. it doesnt connect to the computer which does not give me alot of hope besides of crying for help.

Comment: enter download mode and flash stock ROM from ODIN